# Is there any documentation for vibration and solid mechanics research via Mathematica?

Tags: finite-element-method, parametric-functions, documentation, solidmechanics

I am interested in the **solid mechanics (elastic mechanics and structural mechanics**, etc.), and vibration, is there any **material or documentation** in this aspect **via FEM in Mathematica?**

Comment: Look at [that](https://zbmath.org/?q=si%3A554) and [that](https://zbmath.org/software/554).

Comment: This is the link to the FEM documentation: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementProgramming.html

Comment: In particular, [that survey](https://zbmath.org/1502.74106) may be useful.

Comment: You have seen the [SolidMechanics](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/PDEModels/tutorial/StructuralMechanics/SolidMechanics.html) monograph, right?